# Warning: 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project

Tags: android-ndk

We have the following warning that `ARMEABI` is not targeted by the project.

`WARNING: ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project.`

We are not trying to use ARMEABI, as [it has been deprecated](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) and should no longer be used. Here is the abiFilters from our build.gradle that sets up what we are using, and 'armeabi' is not listed.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {    
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            // these platforms cover 99% percent of all Android devices
        }
```

What is the `android.injected.build.abi` that is mentioned in the error?

What is causing the reference to ARMEABI?

Comment: What version of the gradle plugin are you using? I haven't heard of this issue before but maybe it's something caused by a super old plugin version.

Comment: Using Gradle: 181.5540.7.32.5014246

Comment: Plug-in version, not Gradle version. The one in your build.gradle.

Comment: This one?     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

Comment: Yeah, that one. That's more or less brand new, so my guess is out. Probably try filing a bug at http://b.android.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit this issue too with Android Studio 3.2. In my case it only appears while running app from IDE on ARM-based device, not when building APK / signed APK or running on x86-based emulator.

So I suppose this is a false warning caused by the list of supported ABIs for target device (the list of ABIs in the warning is equal to Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS or Build.CPU_ABI + Build.CPU_ABI2).

Comment: Is this an Android Studio bug then? Should the build even be looking at anything other than the abiFilters that is listed in the build.gradle file? Especially since the one that it is complaining about is deprecated as of NDK-r17.

Comment: This is also happening for me when debugging on my device from Android Studio. I haven't tried other build combinations yet.

Comment: @JimLeask Yes, I think this is an Android Studio bug. There are always plenty of them, especially after major upgrades. ;)) But it doesn't seem to do much harm.